# Attach WIN API hook to WPF event loop

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi

I'm writing GUID bar code scanner. I decided to use WIN API key listener (WinHooks), but I can't attach to WPF event loop.

C# part:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BarCodeScanner
{
    public sealed class GuidScanner : IScanner
    {
        public GuidScanner()
        {
            Subscribe(ScanInternal);
        }

        public GuidScanner(uint threadId)
        {
            SubscribeThread(threadId, ScanInternal);
        }

        public GuidScanner(Module module)
        {
            Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(module);
            SubscribeInstance(Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(module), ScanInternal);
        }

        public event EventHandler<Guid>? Scanned;

        private void ScanInternal(string value)
        {
            if (!Guid.TryParse(value, out var id))
                return;

            var handler = Scanned;
            handler?.Invoke(this, id);
        }

        [DllImport("BarCodeCore", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern UIntPtr Subscribe([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] IScanner.ScanGuid scan);

        [DllImport("BarCodeCore", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern UIntPtr SubscribeThread(uint threadId, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] IScanner.ScanGuid scan);

        [DllImport("BarCodeCore", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern UIntPtr SubscribeInstance(IntPtr handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] IScanner.ScanGuid scan);
    }
}
```

C++ part:

```
Notification InputScanner::pNotify = nullptr;
void InputScanner::StartScanning(Notification notification)
{
    if (notification == nullptr)
        return;

    InputScanner::pNotify = notification;
    this->pHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, InputScanner::ScannerProc, NULL, NULL);
}

void InputScanner::StartScanning(DWORD hThread, Notification notification)
{
    if (notification == nullptr)
        return;
    
    InputScanner::pNotify = notification;
    this->pHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, InputScanner::ScannerProc, NULL, hThread);
}

void InputScanner::StartScanning(HINSTANCE hInstance, Notification notification)
{
    if (notification == nullptr)
        return;

    InputScanner::pNotify = notification;
    this->pHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, InputScanner::ScannerProc, hInstance, NULL);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK InputScanner::ScannerProc(int nCode, WPARAM actionType, LPARAM actionData) {
    log("Procedure is called");

    .... There is buisnes logic ...
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, actionType, actionData);
}
```

How can I add win api hook to wpf/win forms event loop?
It's possible in principle?

If you wan to learn more details, there is project repository https://github.com/ImVogl/BarCodeScanner/tree/master/Source

I tried to

1. attach to os loop SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, InputScanner::ScannerProc, NULL, NULL);
2. attach to thread SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, InputScanner::ScannerProc, NULL, pManagedThradId);
3. attach to main form module SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, InputScanner::ScannerProc, hInstance, NULL);

But no one case didn't work.

Also I checked WH_KEYBOARD type. Results were same.

Comment: What does `SetWindowsHookEx` return?

Comment: It returned success result (Not null value).

Comment: What exactly is not working? The hook proc is not called? Are you setting the hook inside a thread? If so this means that this thread is receiving the events and it needs a proper win32 message loop.

Comment: @JúlioCésarSchincariolFilho 
1) Yes, procedure isn't called.
2) Hook was added inside wpf UI thread (Application imports dll and calls function in this thread).
3) About meesage loop. If I rum my own message loop, hook works. But in this case I capture thread for this loop. E.g. new thread.
If I try to add hook to wpf applicatiion message loop, proc isn't called.